# Java ScheduledExecutorService to run periodically

Tags: java, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I am attempting **to run a job [which contains 3 services should run parallel] for every minute**. Below is my code snippet.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(servicesMap.size());
for (Map.Entry entry : servicesMap.entrySet()) {
    service.submit(new MyService(conn, serviceID)); 
   // here serviceID is id1 id2 id3 these three job should execute parallel
}
```

Note : MyTask implements Callable & servicesMap will be 3 always

If i try to use ScheduledExecutorService then i cannot able to achieve it. 
It says scheduleService.schedule not accepting Callable type parameterts

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduleService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(servicesMap.size());
for (Map.Entry entry : servicesMap.entrySet()) {
    scheduleService.schedule((new MyService(conn, serviceID)), 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Please help to modify ScheduledExecutorService code to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Your `schedule(…)` call contains more arguments than [the method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule(java.util.concurrent.Callable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) has parameters.

I’m not sure what exactly you are after, though. If you would like to run your service in one minute in the future, then use the following call:

```
scheduleService.schedule(new MyService(conn, serviceID), 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If, instead, you would like to run your service every minute (starting immediately), then use one of the following two calls:

```
scheduleService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyService(conn, serviceID), 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
scheduleService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new MyService(conn, serviceID), 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

---

Regarding your followup question in the comments:

> How to make, within a minute Service1 Service2 Service3 should run parallel, then next minute do the same.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduleService = …;
Collection<Callable<Void>> services = …;
Runnable svcRunner = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Collection<Future<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>(services.size());
        // start all services in parallel
        for (Callable<Void> service : services) {
            // any ExecutorService would do here, i.e., doesn't have to be a
            // ScheduledExecutorService
            futures.add(scheduleService.submit(service));
        }
        // wait for all services to complete
        for (Future<Void> future : futures) {
            try {
                future.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO do something meaningful
            }
        }
    }
};
// run the scheduler every minute (i.e., one minute after the last service
// has finished), starting now
scheduleService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(svcRunner, 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

For simplicity, I have stored the services in a collection. If required, you can also create them anew each time.

Comment: Noted Chriki. So this will run Service1 Service2 Service3 indpendent & parallel every minute right. How to make, within a minute Service1 Service2 Service3 should run parallel, then next minute do the same.

Comment: Chriki.. for loop - it will loop three times. inside loop, i wrote scheduleService.schedule. is it correct?

Comment: We are triggering notification service batch. This batch will run for every minute. 
we need to run 3 services parallel within every minute, those three services will trigger an email & sms to different set of customers.
This thing i am trying to achieve it. Kindly let me know if my explain is not understand.

Comment: if you don't mind, can you please tell me, for this kind of job, whether we need to use connection pooling or how to manage connections and if we need to stop this service how to shut down it.

Comment: The given code should work for your scenario. To be able to later cancel the scheduled services runner, you should keep track of the [returned](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) [`ScheduledFuture<?>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) and `cancel()` it when required. As for the connection pooling question you might want to rather create a new question on SO.

Comment: Ok Thanks & Noted Chriki.